# PHP post response takes too much time for images

Tags: php, forms, post, image-processing, canvas

i'm building a form page for create an ad, and this requires the addition of 1 or more images, so the user must compile the form, add the images, and send it with POST for go to the preview page before the ad is published.

The problem is the time taken by POST process for load the images, it's too much, is there a way for reduce this time? i know there is a method for resize the images with Canvas before the uploading, but what about the original file sent by the form with POST?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `i/o` speed of virtual machines is not good. Sometimes the webservers allow only one connection from browser. You have to analyze what's going on on your server.

- **Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069977/server-take-long-time-to-response)**.

Comment: Yes, i've a virtual development server with low performances, i figured that could be the problem.. so are problems of network bandwidth and hardware, there is anything more i can do for reduce the amount of bytes sent by POST?